# counts/frequencies based on two columns

Tags: r

I have a table that looks like this

```
ID Length OHR
A  23     .34
B  45     .23
C  89     .24
```

I would like to process this to generate another table where the cells contain the count of values that falls within a given range in length as well as OHR (i.e for example of all values that are under length of 10, 2 have OHR values between 0 and 0.1 and so on...)

```
Length/OHR 0-0.1 0.1-0.2 0.2-0.3
0-10        2       3       4
11-20       3       3       4
20-30       1       7       8
```

If it is for one column I can use cut to get the counts but here I need to find the counts based on two columns. I can use combinations of conditional statements in other programming languages to achieve this but it will make the code look messy and even slower too. Given that R is designed to manipulate such data I thought there might be an elegant way to achieve this in R. So, I would like to know how to go about this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Ram.

Comment: You can use `recode` from car package or use `ifelse` or `cut`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a dummy data frame mimicking your data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Length = floor(runif(10,0,100)), OHR = runif(10))
head(df)
#  Length       OHR
#1     28 0.9568333
#2     78 0.4533342
#3     40 0.6775706
#4     88 0.5726334
#5     94 0.1029247
#6      4 0.8998250
```

Use `cut` to make the grouping classes (adjusting the optional argument `breaks` as desired)

```
df$Length.cut <- cut(df$Length, breaks = 10*(0:10))
df$OHR.cut <- cut(df$OHR, breaks = (0:10)/10)
```

Then use `table( , )` to create the 2D contingency table as desired:

```
table(df$Length.cut, df$OHR.cut)
```

Of course the assignment of extra columns is only instructive (to see what `cut` is doing), you can just do

```
table(cut(df$Length, breaks = 10*(0:10)), cut(df$OHR, breaks = (0:10)/10))
```

without the intermediate steps.